# How to specify input and output paths from cmd.exe for a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm a beginner with PowerShell, and a total newb with the command line.  I have a PowerShell script that I want others to run via cmd.exe.  It looks like this:

```
 Get-Content $i | (Do stuff with strings) | Out-file $o
```

Where "i" and "o" are string variables for input and output I want to be     chosen by users.
  I made a batch file and it all works as intended, running from cmd.  My problem is that I want users to be able to specify their input and output paths from the command line, without opening PowerShell.  How can I do this?

Comment: Output user input path to a text file in cmd, and input the path from powershell

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31804858/edit) the question and show what command you're using to launch this from the batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in batch do...

```
set /p IN=[Enter an input path]
set /p OUT=[Enter an output path]
```

then call your PS script with the 2 variables on the end

```
yourscript.ps1 %IN% %OUT%
```

Then in your PS script set it up to take some parameters...

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [string]$INpath,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
  [string]$OutPath
)

Get-Content $INpath | (Do stuff with strings) | Out-file $OutPath
```

That might help you

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  Only the last piece with the cmdletbinding mattered.  Can you explain that syntax a bit to me?  Is that a PS Function?

Comment: As I understand it, its not so much a function but a structure you use to setup a script (or a function / sub within a script) so that its able to take in parameters, know what type they are and to know what position they are on the cmd line.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/07/07/weekend-scripter-cmdletbinding-attribute-simplifies-powershell-functions.aspx
http://windowsitpro.com/blog/what-does-powershells-cmdletbinding-do

Someone else may have a better explanation.