# How to run a powershell script file from within a bat file and pass multiple parameters

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I want to call test.bat which again triggers the Powershell.exe with the file test

**test.bat:**

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "test1.ps1 -Param1 Value1 -Param2 Value2"
```

**test1.ps1:**

```
param{$Tag,$CommitId}

Write-Host $Tag
Write-Host $CommitId
```

Both files are put on the same directory.

At the moment I get an error that my file does not have a .ps1 extension but thats not true... but I guess that is because I pass the parameters in a wrong way...

So how do I correctly pass the parameters to the call in the My.bat?

Comment: Check [this out][1]...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804858/how-to-specify-input-and-output-paths-from-cmd-exe-for-a-powershell-script/31805422#31805422

...The [cmdletbinding] might help you out

Comment: Does not help "yourscript.ps1 %IN% %OUT%d" I need to see the full statement. I am a powershell beginner and already repent it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from batch test.bat might look like this

```
@echo off
set Param1="some text"
set Param2="Some more text"

test1.ps1 %Param1% %Param2%
```

Thats how I would pass parameters to a powershell script. You dont     necessarily have to run powershell.exe with all the other parameters

In the PS1 file I would then do:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
[string]$Tag,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=2)]
[string]$commitId
)

write-host $tag
write-host $CommitId
```

If you absoloutley needed the other switches against powershell.exe you could maybe do..

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "test1.ps1" %Param1% %Param2%
```

Comment: The name of the variable %Param1% is it bound to the name inside the .ps1 file or is the order determining wether %Param1% is passed to $Tag which is defined at first?

Comment: If I understand you right the order is determined by the "Position" part in the cmdlet binding.

so in the above snippet $Tag would be assigned the value of %param1% as %param1% appears at position 1 on the cmdline.

If the script was called using test1.ps1 %param2% %param1% then $tag would be assigned the value of %param2%

Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant and it works as expected. There is a natural order! Thanks a bunch Shovers_!

Answer (score 0):

I would just change test.bat to

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "test1.ps1 -Tag Value1 -CommitId Value2"
```

Of course changing the Value1 and Value2 to the actual values you want to pass.

Comment: Do you have proof that this works? It fails to run anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your test.bat

```
powershell -command "&{C:\temp\script.ps1 -Tag Value1 -CommitId Value2"}"
```